# C# Paging doesnt work for new rows added to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, wcf-data-services

There is a GRID on UI which displays page by page information as ">>" button is clicked. This button fetches data from database using a stored proc using row_number() concept. I am passing the starting row number and ending row number from my UI and accordingly to the stored proc and the query returns the values from the table. The sql query can be thought of (200 and 300 are sample staring and ending row numbers):

```
with y 
as 
(
    select 
      version, 
      Id ,
      row_number() over (order by Id,version) r 
    from 
      X
)
select 
  Id,
  version 
from 
   y 
where 
   r>200 and r<300
```

This works all fine until a new version for existing Id enters the table. In that case the row_number() for existing rows change, and the paging function gets messed up.

Please help!!! need to meet a deadline tomorrow.

Comment: Can we see your db schema, please?

Comment: This Proof Of Concept presentation to client, schema can be changed if you have a better design in mind .. It is a contract table with ID of Contract and Version together as primary key. A lot of terms of the contract are there which will be the columns. The version is to maintain a trail of changes made to any contract.

Comment: When a contract of ID 1 and version 1 is modified, a new row gets added as ID 1 and version 2 .. This causes the trouble as ID 2 and version 1 was previously row_number 2, but now Id 2 and version 1 is row_number 3 .. Hope this clarifies the fact!

Comment: Do you want to list all versions, or just the latest for any ID?

Comment: I would like to list all versions too ..

Comment: Let me clarify the fact a little bit more : There is a GRID on UI which displays page by page information as ">>" button and clicking this button fetches data from database using the above query .. so if currently loaded rows in the grid is between 1 to 10 .. and before the user clicks the ">>" button if newer version comes in the database, the row_number() count will not work .. also I need to display all records via paging in GRID

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption: You only want to display the latest version for each ID.*

Ok, you could make sure that 'X' is the filtered list of results, so that it only contains the latest Version for each ID.

**Example data**

For example, if you have the following data -

```
ID | Version
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
1    2
```

To get all data, just return all from that table, which will return all 5 rows (which you're doing now).

**Required results of X**

What you actually want is the following returned -

```
ID | Version
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    1
```

There are many ways to get the latest records in a table, and hundreds of answers of stackoverflow alone.

**Example query of latest record query**

One way (which can be improved) is

```
WITH Y
AS
(
  SELECT
    t.Id,
    MAX(OriginalTable.Ver) as [Verson], 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY t.Id) as rowNumber
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM @OriginalTable) AS t
  INNER JOIN
    OriginalTable ON (t.ID = OriginalTable.ID)   
  GROUP BY
    t.Id
)
SELECT
  Id, [Verson]
FROM
  Y
WHERE
  rowNumber > 2 AND rowNumber < 8
```

The trick is to make sure that 'X' in your query above excludes your duplicate rows, then implement your paging on that list.

**Alternative option**

Saying all that, you could just redesign your tables so you have a table with just ID in there (and whatever other details you need that is not affected by versioning), then another table that contains a record for each version.  But that's another question!

Comment: Let me clarify the fact a little bit more : There is a GRID on UI which displays page by page information as ">>" button and clicking this button fetches data from database using the above query .. so if currently loaded rows in the grid is between 1 to 10 .. and before the user clicks the ">>" button if newer version comes in the database, the row_number() count will not work .. also I need to display all records via paging in GRID